# What is the difference between normal MVC and Azure MVC forms authentication systems?

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, visual-studio-2013, forms-authentication

I see in Visual Studio 2013 when creating a default MVC application and creating a Windows Azure cloud service MVC application that the Forms authentication tables differ:

Normal MVC:

- UserProfile
- webpages_Membership
- webpages_OAuthMembership
- webpages_Roles
- webpages_UsersInRoles

Azure MVC:

- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserClaims
- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUsers

Questions:

- What is the name for each system (for Googling)?
- Why are they different?
- Which is the more recent\better system that I should use?

Even the code for AccountController.Register() differs:

Normal MVC:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

Azure MVC:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure way is called ASP.NET Identity and is MVC 5. The old way is called ASP.NET membership.

The new way is more powerful.

Resources are here: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources

Comment: ASP.Net Identity is not connected to Azure, stand-alone component. You can have web-applications in Azure with either Identity or with Membership. Makes no difference for the hosting platform.